# Extract Match URL in data studio

Tags: sql, regex, looker-studio

I am trying to get specific part of a url from my website in data studio. This is the url type:

```
https://mywebsite.com/acs/region/USA/news/asdf.com
https://mywebsite.com/acs/region/ARG/news/asdf2.com
https://mywebsite.com/acs/dtcp/en-us/news/asdf3.com
```

And I would like to get:

```
region/USA
region/ARG
dtcp/en-us/
```

This is the code that I tried it:

```
/[a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+/
```

But in data studio print NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
/acs/([^/]+/[^/]+)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aobywu/1). *Details*:

- `/acs/` - a literal string
- `([^/]+/[^/]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than `/`, `/` and then again one or more chars other than `/`
- `/` - a `/` char